# how to do with .xib files for ios6 and older versions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I am createing my project on ios 6 but as per requirement the same project should be working in both ios 6 and older versions.

then how can I manage the .xib file for both versions because in ios 6 we have large .xib file.

Should I create new .xib file for older versions?

share your ideas friends,

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You don't need to make separate nib files for iOS 6 and other lower OS versions. The only thing you need to follow is to disable "Use Auto Layout" feature of every nib in xcode 5 and can use autoresize property of views for making the view compatible for iOS 6 and other lower versions.

Comment: and dont use the new controls of ios6 or have replicates of those new Views in your bundle

Answer (score 0):

Create Two Xib Files one for iphone5 and other work for iPhone 3GS/4//4s one class

then

check for the device Idiom and height and it will work as following...

```
#define isiPhone5 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)


    if(isiPhone5 == 1)
    {
        nibName = @"DesclaimerViewiPhone5";
    }
    else
    {
        nibName = @"DesclaimerView";
    }
    DesclaimerView* Obj = [[DesclaimerView alloc]initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationControl pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```